# How to Generate Java Pojo from Swaggerhub Api during Gradle build?

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, pojo, swaggerhub

My application publishes data to an application owned by another person. The model for the object is owned by that other person but they provide an API hosted in Swaggerhub for that same model.

I want to automate the process of the model creation, so that the effort is minimal from my side and it doesn't need a constant changes. I want to build the models from the Swaggerhub Api directly and then I want to use that model in my app to create the data objects (POJO). Every build that runs will then update it automatically.

I hope to accomplish this through the gradle. I use gradle to build my application.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!